# Username not displaying in URL even when specifying Rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I am really struggling understanding how to modify URL using Rewrite rules. I have seen the following link : [Directly adding username to URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819284/directly-adding-username-to-url-php) - but the following knowledge does not seem to work for me.

I need the url to say eg. 
`http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy`

Rather than:
`http://localhost/profile_page.php`

**.htaccess** (Which is located in in the default Wamp folder, C:\wamp\www)

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wamp/www/

    RewriteRule ^/?$ profile_page.php
    RewriteRule ^/me?$ profile_page.php
    RewriteRule ^/profile_page.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1
    RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1
    RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1
```

**I have the following questions:**

**1.** With the rules above, although I have limited knowledge in this field, I expect it to convert the url of `http://localhost/profile_page.php` to display the name of the user logged in i.e. `http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy`.

Details of the user who are logged in can be gained from the session variable `$username` or the variable `$user` which obtains the username of the user after "u=" in the url (see below). However, the url does not display the name of the user logged in, it just says `http://localhost/profile_page.php` when, if logged in as Freddy, I want it to say `http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy`.

```
<?php
    $user = "";
    if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $user = ($_GET['u']);
        if (ctype_alnum($user)) { //check if the user exists
            $check = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($check) === 1) {
                $get        = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
                $user       = $get['username'];
                $fname      = $get['first_name'];
                echo "<h2>Profile page for: $user</h2>";
            } else { // refresh page 
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/index.php\">";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**2.** If, in the URL, I type `http://localhost/profile_page.php?u=Fred`, it echo's it is on Fred's page, but displays the profile page of the user logged in, so it displays posts and information for Freddy, rather than Fred, as specified in the URL.

Comment: @anubhava - Is the `RewriteBase` incorrect? I understand that the `RewriteBase` provides a base for your rewrites but assumed this meant the root folder.

Comment: @anubhava - Right, I think I got it now. Thanks, I have changed the the RewriteBase to `RewriteBase /`. But the same issues persist, the URL is not displaying the username or allowing me to jump to another users profile page by tying in their username in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your .htaccess with this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(me)?/?$ profile_page.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^profile(?:_page)?/([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile_page.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I have completely changed my `.htaccess` file to the code you have provided. As stated in my question, the url currently (even with the new .htaccess file) appears as `http://localhost/profile_page.php`, when a user first clicks onto their profile button (profile_page.php) I want the URL to instantly print their username in the url i.e. `http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy`.

Comment: I also need the content after the `/` to direct to the users profile. I.e. from `http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy` I can edit the URL to i.e. `http://localhost/profile_page/Alice` and be directed to Alice's profile page. Or do I require additional code for this functionality? Nevertheless, the edited .htaccess file is performing in the same way the previous file was.

Comment: Thanks, I have started to see a couple features which use the `$user` variable now show the user's username. However, when I edit the URL and write, for example, `http://localhost/profile_page/Alice` (who is a valid user) - the page it is redirected to is the page for the current user who is logged on, the only difference is that the CSS on this new rendered page is non existent. In addition to this, going to home.php (by clicking the logo) from `http://localhost/profile_page/Alice` the URL then changes to `http://localhost/profile_page/home.php` and gives me a 404 Not found error.

Comment: Good news, the page now loads with the appropriate CSS, so many thanks. Bad news, the page is still loading the same content i.e. `http://localhost/profile_page/alice` displays the same page as  `http://localhost/profile_page/freddy` such as the same profile picture as Freddy etc - Meaning the page for Alice, is not being loaded even if the URL says it is on Alice's page?

Comment: My complete .htaccess file at this current point in time, is the answer you have provided above. Also, if I want the URL to instantly display the users name in the URL would that involve additional rules? i.e. Assuming Freddy is logged in, from `http://localhost/home.php`, I click on the `profile` button which takes me to `http://localhost/profile_page.php`, can the URL be set to instantly display his name in the URL? so as soon as I click on `profile`, it will say`http://localhost/profile_page./freddy`? Although, the biggest concern at the moment is the url directing users the correct page.

Comment: I have edited the source, the `profile` button now forwards the user to `http://localhost/profile_page` but still does not display the users name in the URL. When I type `http://localhost/profile_page/alice` in the URL, the echo statement `echo "<h2>Profile page for: $user</h2>"; ` (See question above), it echo's the username of whoever is typed after the `/`, meaning the if statement is being executed, but just not directing the user to the corresponding page.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your comment. Nevertheless, the URL now states the names of the user logged in when going on profile_page.php. The URL now states `http://localhost/profile_page/Freddy` as he is the logged in user. However, again, when editing the URL to `http://localhost/profile_page/Alice`, it is still keeping me on Freddy's profile page?

Comment: If browser URL `http://localhost/profile_page/Alice` shows and it shows Freddy's profile page to you then it is 100% code issue. To check whether correct username is passed print `$_GET['u']` and it should show `Alice` not `Freddy`

Comment: That's the issue. See if I am logged in as Freddy, the URL is `http://localhost/profile_page/freddy`, and when I echo `$_GET['u']` it will print `freddy`. But, then when I edit the URL to `http://localhost/profile_page/alice`, it will echo out `alice` but keep me on Freddy's profile page.

Comment: Agreed. Anyway, thank you for all your help! Much appreciated :)